# Is there a way to create a command for a discord.js bot that pulls up images from Google?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been thinking to create a function for my discord.js V12 bot, so on command it pulls up various images from Google. Users who are familiar with bots like NotSoBot will know what I'm talking about. I'm looking for something like a .img ( insert search query here ) and the bot will search it up on google images and return various results in an embed. I don't have the code because I need some suggestions before I can start making the function.

Comment: Google has made this harder these days. The official way is via https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview which costs money if doing more than 100 searches per day. There are also meta APIs like https://serpapi.com/images-results which can provide this at a cost. Otherwise you are looking to scrape Google Image results yourself, which has Google ToS implications. There are some packages which solve this on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=google%20image) but use at your own risk. They may give you some ideas, though.

Comment: Maybe you should try using the [dogpile](https://www.dogpile.com/) api